# Spring boot app restart after spring batch job complete

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have spring boot app which should export a table in the database (product) as `csv` file so I am using spring batch to do that, my problem is that, when the job complete the app is restarted I think it is because spring batch close the entity manager after finish but I am not sure

**note 1:** I am using `JpaPagingItemReader` as reader.

**note 2:** I am starting the job from controller using `JobLuncher`

**note 3:** I know that the batch processing is working async so the controller return result before the job complete, i hope to find way to change this too.

**note 4:** I stopped the auto lunch of jobs using `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in my application properties

**note 5:** I found a question for similar issue but it has no answer and closed (duplicated) but it is not and that was different problem.

**my code:**

-batch config:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @PersistenceUnit
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public JpaPagingItemReader<Product> reader() {
        JpaPagingItemReader<Product> ir = new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<Product>().name("productReader")
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory).queryString("select p from Product p").pageSize(500)
                .build();
        return ir;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductItemProcessor processor() {
        return new ProductItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Product> writer() {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<Product> aggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Product>();
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Product>  extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames(new String[] { "id", "name", "price" });
        aggregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor);

        FlatFileItemWriter<Product> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Product>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("prices.csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(aggregator);

        return writer;
    }

     @Bean
     public Step step1() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Product, Product> chunk(100)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
     }

     @Bean
     public Job exportUserJob() {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();
     }


    }
```

-controller:

```java
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(HttpSession session) {
        try {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return "Done";

    }
```

this is the console:
[image: console]

after job complete with:

```
2020-01-06 14:02:03.570  INFO 4456 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=exportUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{time=1578312121885}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

it shut down and close the jpa:

```
2020-01-06 14:02:04.911  INFO 4456 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-06 14:02:04.918  INFO 4456 --- [       Thread-7] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-06 14:02:04.955  INFO 4456 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-06 14:02:04.989  INFO 4456 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.co-mada</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mada_Website</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Mada_Website</name>
    <description>Mada Company Website</description>
    <!-- Packaging -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring batch dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MadaWebsiteApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MadaWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return builder.sources(MadaWebsiteApplication.class);
    }


}
```

i hope everything clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you below configuration to applicaion.properties

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
```